# IIS caches things, even when I disable output caching

Tags: iis-7.5, cache

I have an IIS web server on my local network for development purposes, and I want to disable all caching mechanisms. IIS seems to be caching everything, even when I disable output caching like so:

[image: Output Caching window]

I have set the above at the root of my webserver.

The weird thing is that I need to request a file a few times before it starts caching it.

I know that it can't be a client side related issue as I checked that they were requesting a fresh copy from the server each time.

Example of what I did:

1. I create a HTML file
2. I navigate to the above HTML file on the server (e.g. `http://example/path/to/file/test.html`) in my browser, and refresh the page a few times.
3. I change the HTML file on the disk
4. I refresh the page in my browser again, but I still see the old HTML file, and not the new one that I had saved to the disk in `step 3`.

IIS version: 7.5, Windows version: Windows 7

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Are you sure it's not the *client* that's doing the caching here. Have you tried clearing the client browser cache after you change the file on the web server?

Comment: @ChrisMcKeown Yes, I am sure that the problem is server side - I have cleared the cache in between page loads.

Comment: Any proxy servers in between the client and the server that might be doing the caching?

Comment: You should be able to look at the headers to see what it's throwing at you. If you get a `304 Not Modified` response then something in between is caching your results.

Comment: @ChrisMcKeown No, I am on a local network with no proxies in sight.

Comment: @NathanC I am getting 200 OKs back from the server, but it is still caching as he page returned by the IIS 7.5 server is not the latest version that I saved to my hard drive. The only way to fix it is to restart the IIS server.

Comment: Have you found the solution to this problem? I'm experiencing the same issue and can't disable the goddamn cache in any way

Comment: @Tivie No, unfortunately I have not :(

Comment: this is the saddest thing ever.

Comment: Yet another example of why Windows is a garbage OS for websites.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this an old thread. However, I'm having the same issue and having trouble finding more information about it.

What may help though is a somewhat related article explaining this exact issue, where disabling Output caching the IIS way didn't help. What these guys did was disable/remove the module altogether. This is the only promising bit of information I have at the moment.

Here's the (old) post: https://www.lightmaker.com/get-your-iis-output-caching-right-for-sitecore-multisite-implementations/

**Update:** This hasn't resolved my issue, so there is something else in my case causing the caching. I'll leave the reply in in case it does help someone else.

Comment: I don't have a windows machine handy to test this on anymore, but this sounds like the best solution I've seen yet. If it works for you I'll accept this as the answer :D

Comment: Unfortunately, this hasn't resolved our issue.

Comment: Awww, drat! If you do ever find a solution - do keep us updated :-)